# How to add paragraphs of contents in an Android app?

Tags: android, sdk, menuitem

I am creating an Android app for a college website. Now I want to add contents to each menu items, which on click should display paragraphs, images, etc. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to do this:

- You can use two activities. `ActivityA` for the menu list and `ActivityB` for each list item's details when one is clicked on a menu item in `ActivityA`.
- You can use an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: Thank You Wasim, how to start a new activity?

Comment: now..you have to use Intents..

to start activity from activityA to ActivityB..you can do like ths:

Intent i=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivityforResult(i,0);